# what does cache means in POST and GET

Tags: java, http, servlets, post, get

I have seen that that one of the main difference between POST and GET is that POST is not cached but GET is cached.

Could you explain me what do you mean about "cache"?

Also, if I use POST or GET server sends me response. Is there any difference? In all of cases, I have request data and response, is not it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *Cache* (in the context of HTTP) means to store a page/response either on the client or some intermediate host - perhaps in a content distribution network.  When the client requests a page, then the page can be served from the client's cache (if the client requested it before) or the intermediate host.  This is faster and requires fewer resources than getting the page from the server that generated it.

One downside is that if the request changes some state on the server, that change won't happen if the page is served from a cache.  This is why POST requests are usually not served from a cache.

Another downside to caching is that the cached copy may be out of date.  The HTTP caching mechanisms try to prevent this.

Comment: where is this cache?  The browser?  The server?  The router?

Comment: @johnk - The primary cache that most people think about is in the browser.   There are often caches on the server side - dedicated machines owned/rented by the content provider which serve pages and only hit the origin server when necessary.  There are also content distribution networks (CDNs for short).   These are companies that serve other company's content all over the world.  CloudFlare is one CDN.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea behind the GET and POST methods is that a GET message only retrieves information but *never* changes the state of the server. (Hence the name). As a result, just about any caching system will assume that you can remember the last GET response returned, and that the next one will look the same.

A POST on the other hand is a request that sends new information to the server. So not only can these not be cached (because there's no guaruantuee that the next POST won't modify things even more; think +1 like buttons for example) but they actually have to invalidate parts of the cache because they might modify pages.

As a result, your browser for example will warn you when you try to refresh a page to which you POSTed information, because you might make changes you did not want made by doing so. When GETting a page, it will not do so because you cannot change anything on the site by doing so.

(Or rather; it's your job as a programmer to make sure that nothing changes when GETting a page.)

Comment: Note that "nothing changes" means nothing significant in the context of your app.

Comment: I understand when to use GET and when POST. I'm interested in what does word "cache" means. :)

Answer (score 0):

GET is supposed to return the same result from the server and not change things at the server side and hence idempotent.

Whereas POST means it can modify something at the server(make an entry in db, delete something etc) and hence not idempotent.

And with regards to caching the data in GET has been addressed here in a nice manner.

> http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/08/20/caching-http-post-requests-and-responses/#.VGy9ovmUeeQ